# Is there a way to program I OpenCL without 3rd party plugins? C#

Tags: c#, kernel, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I realise the question of how to run C# on the GPU is a common question but my question is a bit different. Is there a way to do it without 3rd party frameworks (such as Cudafy). I don't  want to use plugins because I'm making a program which I intend to be 100% my own code (personal ambition) and in feel I won't learn as much if I do.

Would I simply need to create a kernel and compile it and call it from c# (process.start()) or is there a better way of doing it.

How do I go about making a kernel? I am beginner with GPGPU so sorry for my ignorance. However, I am a very advanced c# programmer.

Comment: You can't use opencl in C# without C# bindings or without using C++ dll. You need somehow bind opencl.lib and some header files but you can't do  that in C#. Khronos' site gives C++ headers only. Start with C++ then. You'll need it later anyway. Why? For example, to map a memory area to GPU copy engines, you need the source buffer to be aligned on say 4096-bytes-multiple. C# doesn't have this but easily done inside C++. Another example could be C# moving all buffers unless you pin them. If you don't create them from C++, gpu-cpu communication performance suffers.

Comment: I think you can use hlsl to do it that isnt opengl.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, I have finally come up with a solution to my issue. I created bindings to the (unmanaged) OpenCL.dll. It then uses some tricks to be able to run the code on the GPU by using an attribute. The best way I can describe it is like Cudafy, but it is quite different.

Thanks to those who replied to my question.